# Error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token Node()

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So, I keep getting an error saying I need an unqualified-id and cant figure out what is giving me the error.
please help.

the error occurs on the `Node()` part of the class.

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  Node()
       ^
```

Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   class AHuffman
   {

   public:
          class Node
          {
                  Node* right_child;
                  Node* left_child;
                  Node* parent;
                  Node* sibling;
                  int weight;
                  int number;
                  string data;
          };

          Node()
          {
                  right_child = NULL;
                  left_child = NULL;
                  parent = NULL;
                  sibling = NULL;
                  weight = 0
                  number = 1;
                  data = "";
          }

  //      int encode(string* msg, char** result, int rbuff_size);
  //      int decode(string* msg, char** result, int rbuff_size);
          AHuffman(string* alphabet);
          ~AHuffman();
  };

  int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
  {
          if(argc != 4){
                  //Invalid number of arguments
                  cout << "invalid number of arguments" << endl;
                  return 1;
          }
          string* alphabet = new string(argv[1]);
          string* message = new string(argv[2]);
          string* operation = new string(argv[3]);


          return 0;

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you put the constructor of Node outside of its class:

Anyway, you should initialize its members in [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of in constructor body.

```
class Node
{
    Node* right_child;
    Node* left_child;
    Node* parent;
    Node* sibling;
    int weight;
    int number;
    string data;
public:
    Node()
      : right_child(0), left_child(0),
        parent(0), sibling(0),
        weight(0), number(1)
    {
    }
};
```

---

Another note, you don't need that much `new` in C++

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a poorly copy pasted code. The 'Node
 constructor first should either have a declaration inside the 'Node' class or move the definition inside as below.

You decla

```
class Node
      {
       private:                  // private members
              Node* right_child;
              Node* left_child;
              Node* parent;
              Node* sibling;
              int weight;
              int number;
              string data;
       public:                  // make it public so the class can actually be constructible 
              Node()
              {
                      right_child = NULL;
                      left_child = NULL;
                      parent = NULL;
                      sibling = NULL;
                      weight = 0;            // and delimiter here
                      number = 1;
                      data = "";
              }
        };
```

Comment: ok, thank you for pointing those out i did not know the constructor has to be in the declaration.